# Free shared memory on signal interrupt

Tags: c, signals, shared-memory

I'm writing a program in C and I'm creating a couple of child processes which use POSIX shared memory.
Now I am trying to handle the case when the program is interrupted by signal like SIGINT.
I know, I need to install signal function and it isn't good to free resources directly in signal handler because of the inconsistency of the code so it is necessary just to switch the boolean flag.
Meanwhile my main code in is loop until the flag is switched.

So it goes something like this:

```
 bool signal_interrupt = false;     

 void sig_handler(int sig_num)
 {
   signal_interrupt = true;
 }

 int main(void)
 {
   while (!signal_interrupt)
   {
     /* code, arguments processing, functions calling...*/
     signal_interrupt = true;
   }
 }
```

My problem is that I cannot figure how to release the resources in some function of the program. Should the code of the function be in the same loop as shown in the main func? How the program reacts on signal interrupt? It returns from the current function to main and if it finds signal function its handler is called?
Thanks for any advice, I would really like to understand this.

Comment: When your program receive signal, it will cancel the current syscall and will call the signal handler. After your signal handler completes, your program will return to the next syscall, after the interrupted one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, external resources like shared memory do need to be released.

But, system calls are atomic from the point of view of your process so there is no problem with executing them from a signal handler. Just call an external-resource destructor and then exit. (Don't worry about calling free(3).)

Comment: 1. He's using shared memory, so it won't be free'd by the OS. 2. It's good practice  to free all resources on exit, because it's much easier to track memory leaks with valgrind.

Comment: no, the app should end. The problem is that shared memory created with shm_open and semaphores stay in /dev/shm

Comment: @strkol, well, you are right about external resources. For those, however, there is no problem with executing system calls in a signal handler. The usual advice is to avoid `malloc()` and `free().` And calling `free(3)` just before exit has some real negatives and is specifically discouraged in the C++ FAQ. It has been discussed at length here on SO and there are varying opinions.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: There are only a few things you are allowed to do in a signal handler. The usual advice is this - you can only change a value of a variable of type sig_atomic_t and call asynchronous—signal-safe functions. Or use epoll + eventfd and do whatever you want :)

Comment: We are mixing up ISO C and Posix restrictions here. Because the API that's being cleaned up is Posix it seems reasonable to use the more leniant Posix restrictions. And the strict ISO C restriction on changing anything is just to allow register caching and other optimizations, and to effectively insert barriers around shared data structure manipulation. If he is not returning to the program *none* of that matters.

Comment: But what about the case when the signal is sent before my shared mem is created? Or after is was already destroyed in the main code? 
Also my shared memory would have to be a global variable, am I right?
I was said not to unlink the memory in the signal handler and just to use an atomic flag there so I really need to do it this way.